# How to get a String from a field

Tags: java, mysql

I've got a mysql question within java. I've got a mysql database with different tables. I currently got a database called 'litebans' and a table called 'litebans_mutes'.

Within that table there is a row called reason and under that reason (let's say what's within reason) there's a string called 'This is a test' and 'sorry'; how would I get the string 'This is a test' and 'sorry' associated with the same 'uuid' row in java? Here is a picture explaining more:

[Here is an image explaining the sql format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAbhc.jpg)

Additionally, i've currently initialized all variables and such in java, i currently have this code: 
http://hastebin.com/odumaqazok.java (Main class; using it for a minecraft plugin)

The below code is the MySQL class; api used to connect and execute stuff.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import net.octopusmc.punish.Core;

public class MySQL {

    public static Connection openConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            System.err.println(e1);
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + Core.host + ":" + Core.port + "/" + Core.database, Core.user, Core.pass);
            System.out.println("Currently connected to the database.");
            return conn;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured while connecting to the database");
            System.err.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void Update(String qry) {
        try {
            Statement stmt = Core.SQLConn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(qry);

            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            openConnection();
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return Core.SQLConn;
    }

    public static ResultSet Query(String qry) {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            Statement stmt = Core.SQLConn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(qry);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            openConnection();
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
        return rs;
    }
}
```

An example using that api above is shown below:

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = MySQL.Query("QUERY GOES HERE");
    while (rs.next()) {
        //do stuff
    }
} catch (Exception err) {
    System.err.println(err);
    err.printStackTrace();
}
```

tl;dr: I want to get the two fields called 'reason' with the give 'uuid' string field.

Comment: Please try to ask a clear question

Comment: I have; please check the comments down below; people knew what i was clearly asking.

Comment: Some people are just here to try to earn reputation. They don't try to make this platform better by encouraging good questions and discouraging bad ones. It will be a better question if you try to provide some code to back up your question to make it well researched question.

Comment: Thank you for making this community a better place; i'll hopefully add some more statements with available code down here. I hope you could help me more as soon as i post/reply to this question with further details.

Comment: Sure. I will be happy to try.

Comment: I've added more details; hope this helps!

Comment: what the table you want to get eason and uuid ?

Comment: The table is called litebans_mutes and the database is called litebans

Answer (score 0):

First , make sure that your using the jdbc mysql driver to connect to the database

Defile a class where you could write the required connection and create statement code.

**For example**

```
class ConnectorAndSQLStatement {

    ResultSet rs = null;
    public Statement st = null;
    public Connection conn = null;

    public connect() {

        try {
            final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            final String db_url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/your_db_name";

            Class.forName(driver);//Loading jdbc Driver
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, "username", "password");
            st = conn.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("Select what_you_want from your_table_name");
            while (rs.next()) {
                String whatever = rs.getInt("whatever ");
                System.out.print(whatever);
            }
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Just call this function and the magic :D 
Hope it is helpful

Comment: I've added more details; hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for that :)